# Input 'contents' of 'DecodeJpeg' Op has type uint8 that does not match expected type of string

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras-layer

I would like to write my own layer using keras. That do the ELA (Error Level Analysis). The
algorithm is simple encode with "*tf.image.encode_jpeg*" , then decode with "*tf.image.decode_jpeg*" and then *|decoded_img - inputs|*. First "*tf.image.encode_jpeg*" needed a type uint8 so i did a "*inputs = tf.cast(inputs, tf.uint8)*" but then it give me a tyeperror **: Input 'contents' of 'DecodeJpeg' Op has type uint8 that does not match expected type of string. i tried** "*encoded_img = tf.cast(encoded_img, tf.string)*" but it give me : **Value passed to parameter 'x' has DataType string not in list of allowed values: bfloat16, float16, float32, float64, uint8, int8, uint16, int16, int32, int64, complex64, complex128, uint32, uint64**

```
class ELALayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, quality=90, **kwargs):
        super(ELALayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.quality = quality

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Conversion en uint8
        inputs = tf.cast(inputs, tf.uint8)


        fun_enc = lambda x: tf.image.encode_jpeg(x, quality=self.quality)
        encoded_img = tf.map_fn(fun_enc, inputs)
        fun_dec = lambda x: tf.image.decode_jpeg(x, channels=3)
        encoded_img = tf.cast(encoded_img, tf.string)
        decoded_img = tf.map_fn(fun_dec, encoded_img)


        error_map = tf.abs(decoded_img - inputs)


        max_error = tf.reduce_max(error_map)
        ela = error_map / max_error

        return ela

def create_model():
    # Input
    input_img = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

    # ELA Layer
    ela = ELALayer()(input_img)

    # Pretrained ResNet50
    base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')(ela)

    # Output
    output = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=output)
    return model


model = create_model()
```

what do i need to do ?